# How does mass change with speed?

Tags: mass

While reading a textbook on Physics, I came across this :

> Mass is a universal constant. It does not depend upon the position of the body on the Universe but it changes with speed of the body.

It's just two contrasting statements with no further explanation. Maybe the author left it to our curiosity but I can't even find out how mass changes with time.
Thanks
P.S : This is not a homework question.

Comment: This question makes no sense at all. Mass is not a universal constant. Mass does not change with speed either but *momentum* does change relativistically. An object can lose mass over time in various ways, although in most cases no (or very little) mass is actually lost (destroyed).

Comment: What textbook did this come from (author & title)?

Comment: While I wouldn't normally advocate burning books I might be willing to make an exception in this case.

Comment: yes, @Gert is right. The amount of matter doesn't change with speed, it just takes more energy than required to move that amount contributing to "apparent mass increase" (am I right?).

Comment: @JohnRennie: haha, I'll gladly light that pile! Sounds like a 'physics' book coming out of a *Freedumz University*...

Comment: The book is the current revision of a popular academic book on my country, read by most of the students like me. @KyleKanos

Comment: @HGSur: that statement contains neither the author nor the title that I had requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The textbook writer is referring to the concept of [*relativistic mass*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_in_special_relativity), which is the idea that accelerating a body tends to become harder and harder as its speed approaches the speed of light. This is sometimes thought of in terms of an increase in the object's mass as the speed increases.

However, you should think of this as a **deprecated concept** that most modern physicists consider unnecessary and misleading. Nowadays, we prefer to think that the force-acceleration momentum needs to be rephrased to something along the lines of
$$
\mathbf F=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\left[\frac{m_0\mathbf v}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}\right],
$$
with an invariant mass $m_0$, than to introduce a variable "relativistic mass" $m_R=m_0/\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$ in an attempt to clean up that relationship and make it look more classical.